# Error Code: 1822. Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'employee_ibfk_1' in the referenced table 'Collection'

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

Code:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS Company;

-- Creating Company Schema

USE Company;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Collection 
(
  emp_id int not null,
  emp_name varchar(60), 
  numA int ,
  tcol int , 
  amt  int ,
  acol int,
  PRIMARY KEY (emp_id),
  UNIQUE (amt),
  UNIQUE(emp_name)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Employee 
(
  employee_name varchar(60) , 
  FOREIGN KEY (employee_name) REFERENCES Collection(emp_name),
  amount int , 
  FOREIGN KEY (amount) REFERENCES Collection(amt),
  PRIMARY KEY(employee_name)
);

INSERT INTO Employee VALUES ('Bob','200');

-- Insert all records 

INSERT INTO Collection VALUES (1,'Bob',1000,10000, 500, tcol - amt );

-- Select Statements to validate all the tables were created properly

SELECT * FROM Collection;
SELECT * FROM Employee;
```

> Error: Error Code: 1822. Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'employee_ibfk_1' in the referenced table 'Collection'

Answer (score 0):

You aproach is flawed. A foreigney constraint means that you can only add a new row if the data exist in the other other table

For example

```
INSERT INTO Employee VALUES ('Bob','200');
```

Means that in collectives must exist prior to inserting a user named Bob with a amt of 200, which isn't true, as (after switching position there exists only one with amt wit 500

So the reference for amount has to be removed and replaced maybe with a trigger, that check something or other.

try to explain your idea to someone and see if he can folow you

> ```
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Collection 
> (
>   emp_id int not null,
>   emp_name varchar(60), 
>   numA int ,
>   tcol int , 
>   amt  int ,
>   acol int,
>   PRIMARY KEY (emp_id),
>   UNIQUE (amt),
>   UNIQUE(emp_name)
> );
>
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Employee 
> (
>   employee_name varchar(60) , 
>   FOREIGN KEY (employee_name) REFERENCES Collection(emp_name),
>   amount int , 
>   FOREIGN KEY (amount) REFERENCES Collection(amt),
>   PRIMARY KEY(employee_name)
> );
>
> -- Insert all records 
>
> INSERT INTO Collection VALUES (1,'Bob',1000,10000, 500, tcol - amt );
>
>
>
>
> -- Select Statements to validate all the tables were created properly
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO Employee VALUES ('Bob','500');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM Collection;
> SELECT * FROM Employee;
> ```
>
> ```
> emp_id | emp_name | numA |  tcol | amt | acol
> -----: | :------- | ---: | ----: | --: | ---:
>      1 | Bob      | 1000 | 10000 | 500 | 9500
>
> employee_name | amount
> :------------ | -----:
> Bob           |    500
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b343b8e3383f2ed1049245ecb498bc6e)*